# Load Menus from database while layout loading in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, pug, mean-stack, angular-fullstack

i have 2 different layouts in express js , I store all navigation maues in database tables now i have to load menus according to layout e.g home , about, contact for front end layout and dashboard,manage ,ticket for admin Panel in my website.
i stuck on which event or route i have to use for load it.

Comment: Could you post your code here

Comment: ul.nav.navbar-nav
            li
              a.active(href='index.html') Home
            li.dropdown
              a(href='#') Matches
            li.dropdown
              a(href='#') Tournament
            li.dropdown
              a(href='#') Lates News
            li.dropdown
              a(href='#') Organiser
            li.dropdown
              a(href='#') Gallery
            li.dropdown
              a(href='#') Live Video
            li.dropdown
              a(href='#') About Us

Comment: this is jade file code

Comment: post your layout structure of DB here in your question, not in the comment section.